# String manipulation in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I'm using **SQL server 2014**.I  have a column that has text data in it. The data would look like this:

```
create table #temp
(
stringdata varchar(100) NULL
)

insert into #temp values
('CN=ABCD,PN=XYZ,AD=123,AN=rst'),
('AN=ABC,PN=XYZ,CN=12,AN=rst'),
('AN=ABC,CN=XYZ,PN=123,AN=rst'),
('AN=ABC,AN=XYZ,CN=1234567,PN=rst')
```

And I need the result set value that is mapped for `CN`.

I tried to extract the data with the following query:

```
select substring(stringdata,charindex('CN=',stringdata),charindex(',',stringdata)-1),* 
from #temp
```

But the problem is that it takes the 1st index of the comma value. I was not able to provide the correct length.

Is there is any simple query to get the data?

Comment: its SQL server 2014

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the way to split using `SUBSTRING`.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(stringdata,CHARINDEX ('CN=',stringdata)+3
       ,CASE WHEN CHARINDEX (',',SUBSTRING(stringdata,CHARINDEX ('CN=',stringdata)+3,LEN(stringdata)))=0 THEN LEN(stringdata)-1 
             ELSE  CHARINDEX (',',SUBSTRING(stringdata,CHARINDEX ('CN=',stringdata)+3,LEN(stringdata)))-1 END)
FROM #temp
```

Sample Output :

[image]

Comment: What if CN comes at the last position. We don't have ',' delimiter at end position.

Comment: Eg .insert into #temp values
('PN=XYZ,AD=123,AN=rst,CN=ABCD')

Comment: @remi : simply add a case statement,that will handle this case. please use the updated code.

Answer (score 1):

If there are always 4 elements separated by comma, you can use this tricky query:

```
SELECT REPLACE(sdata,'CN=','')
FROM (
    SELECT  PARSENAME(REPLACE(stringdata,',','.'),1) as sdata
    FROM #temp
    UNION
    SELECT  PARSENAME(REPLACE(stringdata,',','.'),2)
    FROM #temp
    UNION
    SELECT  PARSENAME(REPLACE(stringdata,',','.'),3)
    FROM #temp
    UNION
    SELECT  PARSENAME(REPLACE(stringdata,',','.'),4)
    FROM #temp
) p
WHERE sdata LIKE 'CN=%'
```

Output:

```
ABCD
12
XYZ
1234567
```

Answer (score 0):

String operations are painful in SQL Server.  Sometimes I find that `OUTER APPLY` can help:

```
select t.stringdata, t3.sd2 as cn
from #temp t outer apply
     (select stuff(stringdata, 1, charindex('CN=', stringdata), '') as sd1
     ) t2 outer apply
     (select left(sd1 + ',', charindex(',', sd1 + ',')) as sd2
     ) t3
```

Of course, this gets even more complicated if `CN=` is not in the string.  The `+ ','` is to allow the `CN` element to be the last element of the string.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this one:

```
WITH Xmls AS
(
    SELECT CONVERT(xml,'<a>'+REPLACE(stringdata,',','</a><a>')+'</a>') Col FROM #temp
)
SELECT N.value('.', 'varchar(100)')
FROM Xmls
CROSS APPLY Col.nodes('a') T(N)
WHERE N.value('.', 'varchar(100)') LIKE 'CN%'
```

Answer (score 0):

With the help of a parser and a CROSS APPLY, perhaps the following

```
Select A.*
      ,B.Key_PS
      ,Key_Value=Replace(B.Key_Value,'CN=','')
  from #Temp A
  Cross Apply (Select * From [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse] (A.stringdata,',') Where Key_Value like 'CN=%') B
```

Returns

```
stringdata                      Key_PS  Key_Value
CN=ABCD,PN=XYZ,AD=123,AN=rst    1       ABCD
AN=ABC,PN=XYZ,CN=12,AN=rst      3       12
AN=ABC,CN=XYZ,PN=123,AN=rst     2       XYZ
AN=ABC,AN=XYZ,CN=1234567,PN=rst 3       1234567
```

The Parser if needed

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse] (@String varchar(max),@Delimeter varchar(10))
--Usage: Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse]('Dog,Cat,House,Car',',')
--       Select * from [dbo].[udf-Str-Parse]('John Cappelletti was here',' ')

Returns @ReturnTable Table (Key_PS int IDENTITY(1,1), Key_Value varchar(max))
As
Begin
   Declare @XML xml;Set @XML = Cast('<x>' + Replace(@String,@Delimeter,'</x><x>')+'</x>' as XML)
   Insert Into @ReturnTable Select ltrim(rtrim(String.value('.', 'varchar(max)'))) FROM @XML.nodes('x') as T(String)
   Return 
End
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to insert is like this:

```
    insert into #temp values
('CN=ABCD','PN=XYZ','AD=123','AN=rst'),
('AN=ABC','PN=XYZ','CN=12','AN=rst'),
('AN=ABC','CN=XYZ','PN=123','AN=rst'),
('AN=ABC','AN=XYZ','CN=1234567','PN=rst')
```